# Entity Framework Code first : Set unique key constraint is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my application I am using EntityFramework with code first approach. I am using EF7 with ASP.NET 4.6 MVC and VS2015. My model class is like below :

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Email Address.")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index("IX_EA", IsUnique = true)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

}
```

My context file is like below :

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {    
        var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        options.UseSqlServer(connection).UseRowNumberForPaging();
    }
}
```

So, from model class you can see that I want set unique constraint to EmailAddress column in database table means EmailAddress field should contain duplicate value(an email address should not be repeat in table). But when I run the project database successfully get created. but that Unique constraint in not there. I am not getting why it is not setting that constraint on EmailAddress field.

Please help me to set unique constraint to the field using code first approach of EntityFramework.

Comment: Try setting up `Maxlength(200)`

Comment: What do you care about the CONSTRAINT if it creates a unique index? Index is "better" and enforced uniqueness anyway - the constraint is only useful if you do not put an index up. Is the index there?

Comment: It didn't work. And I think length could not be issue

Comment: @TomTom, I didn't get you.

Comment: a unique constraint is useless if you have a unique index. You actually also never ask for a unique CONSTRAINT. Does it create the index or not? What is so hard to understand on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From EF Core [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes#data-annotations):

> Indexes can not be created using data annotations.

But you can use the fluent API to create index :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasIndex(c => c.EmailAddress) // Create an index
        .IsUnique() // that is unique
        .ForSqlServerHasName("IX_EA"); // specify the name 
}
```

You can also use [Alternate keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys)

> An alternate key serves as a alternate unique identifier for each entity instance in addition to the primary key. When using a relational database this maps to the concept of a unique index/constraint. In EF, alternate keys provide greater functionality than unique Indexes because they can be used as the target of a foreign key.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasAlternateKey(c => c.EmailAddress);
}
```

Comment: Using it I got unique value in EmailAddress field. But that index name is different from I have mentioned.

Comment: @MaksymLabutin updated the link to point to ef core documentation. when I worte this answer it was called ef7....

Answer (score 0):

```
[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int FirstColumn { get; set; }

[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public int SecondColumn { get; set; }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.